# 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' Failed to assign to property 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneTextBox.ActionIconTapped'

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm getting a `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException` on Windows Phone. The additional information says:

> Failed to assign to property 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneTextBox.ActionIconTapped'.

Here's the `PhoneTextBox` to which it refers:

```
<toolkit:PhoneTextBox
   Grid.Row="1"
   x:Name="nameInput"
   VerticalAlignment="Top"
   InputScope="Text"
   Hint="Enter your first name"
   ActionIcon="/Assets/next.png"
   ActionIconTapped="nameInput_ActionIconTapped"
/>
```

and the event handler:

```
void nameInput_ActionIconTapped(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   this.NavigationService.Navigate(GreetingPage.BuildNavigationUri(nameInput.Text));
}
```

and here's the method of the GreetingPage:

```
public static Uri BuildNavigationUri(string name)
{
   return new Uri("/GreetingPage.xaml?name=" + name, UriKind.Relative);
}
```

Could you please help to resolve this exception and find out why it doesn't want to assign?

Comment: Solved the problem. Instead of "RoutedEventArgs" should "EventArgs" be used in the event handler parameters. Sample is taken from the book "Windows phone 8 in action" page 50. So be careful chumps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Include `System.Windows.Interactivity`:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

And then add the following:

```
<toolkit:PhoneTextBox ActionIcon="/Assets/feature.search.png">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="ActionIconTapped">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</toolkit:PhoneTextBox>
```

Answer taken from following link:

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/14299/how-to-map-the-actionicontapped-event-handler-of-phonetextbox-using-mvvmcross

Comment: Underscores the <i:Interaction.Triggers> and says that there is no Interaction name in namespace "clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"